# fobjc-arc error from xcodebuild in jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I'm getting an error when trying to build a MacOs app using Jenkins:

```
error: -fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /var/folders/cn/n0sjm_hx1pdg92gkg49r3tgc0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.2-6C131e/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/DatabaseBuilder2_Prefix-bvnwqzcnsgjinzgqoundsgsrsuxd/DatabaseBuilder2_Prefix.pch.pch DatabaseBuilder2_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It looks like it's running this command (I got it from the full jenkins logs):

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target DatabaseBuilder4 -configuration Release clean build
```

I can cd into the project directory and run that command from a terminal and it seems to work.  What am I missing?